# Kendo UI TreeView right click

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-treeview

I have some kendo treeView with remote data.
Also I have context menu that activates on right click,
Is it possible to select node manualy ? I mean that this node must be highlighted like it is left mouse click. Maybe it is bossible to trigger some event ? Please help

```
    $("#myTree").on('mousedown', '.k-item', function (event) {
        if (event.which === 3) {
            var treeView = $('#myTree').data('kendoTreeView');     
            var dataSource = treeView.dataSource;
            var itemUId = $(this).attr("data-uid");
            var node = dataSource.getByUid(itemUId);                        
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can add :

```
$("#myTree").on('mousedown', '.k-item', function (event) {
    if (event.which === 3) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // to avoid propagation of this event to the root of the treeview
        $('#myTree').data('kendoTreeView').select(this);                        
    }
})
```